# Prove that two vectors are collinear given $x_iy_j=x_jy_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given two non-zero vectors
>   $$
> \mathbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_n),\quad\mathbf{y}=(y_1,\cdots,y_n),\quad
> $$
>   and the conditions
>   $$
> \forall i,j \quad x_iy_j=x_jy_i.
> $$
>   How do I derive that there is a non-zero $r$ such that
>   $$
> \mathbf{x} = r \mathbf{y}\quad ?
> $$

I can work out the case $n=2$ by cases. wlog $x_1\ne 0$ ($\mathbf{x}\ne 0$ thus one of the components is non-zero)

1. $y_2=0$

   1. $y_1=0$, contradiction with $\mathbf{y}\ne 0$
   2. $y_1\ne 0$

      1. $x_2=0$, then $(x_1,0)=\frac{x_1}{y_1}(y_1,0)$
      2. $x_2\ne 0$, contradiction with $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$
2. $y_2\ne 0$, then $(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2}{y_2}(y_1,y_2)$

I think that this proof is correct but not nice. In any case it get complex with growing $n$ and I do not see how to set up an induction proof.
Is there a nice proof valid for any $n$.

Comment: It's not exactly true the way it's written. For example if $\vec{x}$ is the vector with all $1$s, and $\vec{y}=\vec{0}$, then you cannot write $\vec{x}=r\vec{y}$ for any $r$. You could add a condition that the vectors have nonzero entries to avoid this.

Comment: You correctly assume that if $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0}$, then one of the $x_i$, for instance $x_1$ is nonzero.  But you didn't use that in the rest.  So why not argue from the standpoint that division by $x_1$ is safe?

Comment: @alex.jordan I assumed that both vectors are non-zero at the beginning

Comment: @MatthewLeingang , you are correct

Comment: @PeptideChain Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your proof for $n=2$, the distinction whether $x_2 = 0$ or $x_2 \ne 0$ is not necessary. You have
$$
 (x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1}{y_1}(y_1,y_2) \text{ if } y_1 \ne 0
$$
and
$$
 (x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2}{y_2}(y_1,y_2) \text{ if } y_2 \ne 0 \, .
$$
This argument can be extended to arbitrary dimensions. Note that the conclusion holds even if one or both vectors are zero.

---

*Proof* (sketch) for arbitrary $n$:

If $\mathbf{y}=(0,\ldots,0)$ then $\mathbf{y} = 0 \mathbf{x}$ and the vectors are collinear.

Otherwise pick one index $i$ with $y_i \ne 0$, define $r = \frac{x_i}{y_i}$, and then show that $\mathbf{x} = r \mathbf{y}$.

---

Or in a more symmetric fashion: If $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y} = (0,\ldots,0)$ then the vectors are trivially collinear.

Otherwise pick one index $i$ with $(x_i, y_i) \ne (0, 0)$, and show that $y_i \mathbf{x} - x_i \mathbf{y} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_j \ne 0$, then $$\frac{x_i}{x_j}=\frac{y_i}{y_j} = \alpha_{ij}$$.

Let $p$ be the first index where $x_p \ne 0$.

$$x_1 =\cdots =x_{p-1} = 0 = y_1 =\cdots =y_{p-1}$$

Loop from $p$ to $n$, $$x_j = \alpha_{pj} x_p$$ and $$y_j=\alpha_{pj} y_p$$ so $$r=\frac{y_p}{x_p}.$$

Comment: Your example is flawed: $x_1y_2=1$, but $x_2y_1=0$.

Comment: the -1 is not from me (just in case the completely unmotivated -1 of my Q is from you; the two events where causally ordered and very close; but possibly a coincidence)

Comment: You are right.  That was flawed, no such counter-example.  Fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: Well no.  I did not "take revenge" and strike out with a "-1".  Somebody else seems not to like your question (I don't know why, I like it).